# How to keep img element adjacent to text?

Tags: html, image, layout

I feel sure this must be a FAQ, but I haven't found the answer yet.

I have a small image run in with some text on an HTML page. The image needs to stay with the word that follows it but despite using an `&nbsp;` between the two or even putting them directly next to one another, Firefox sometimes puts a line break in between.

I should also confess that the `<img>` is wrapped as the content of an `<a>` element, if that makes a difference.

edit - here's a test file that show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
&middot; <a href="example.com"; onmouseover="return true"><img height="9" width="9" src="logo-break.gif" alt="pic" /></a>2UXX&nbsp;B:308-375
&middot; <a href="example.com"; onmouseover="return true"><img height="9" width="9" src="logo-break.gif" alt="pic" /></a>2V1D&nbsp;B:308-375
</body>
</html>
```

If you display that page and slowly make the browser narrower, the line breaks after the second image. There's no css involved.

edit2 - I posted a stripped down example at http://jsfiddle.net/487R7/  That version doesn't have the `<a>` element at all and does include `&nbsp;` entities. Fiddle with the width of the result box to see the symptoms.

Comment: Is display:inline what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: since FF sometimes puts a line break in between then it's probably the container width is not wide enough so it wraps. Post some code

Comment: @Andre, I don't think so. The images are definitely displayed inline, which I think is the default. It's just how the text flows.

Comment: @j08691, Here's a sample: ` &middot;       <a href="http://example.com" onmouseover="some stuff"><img height="9" width="9" src="/images/logo.gif" alt="pic" /></a>2UXX&nbsp;B:308-375
 &middot;       <a href="http://example.com" onmouseover="some stuff"><img height="9" width="9" src="/images/logo.gif" alt="pic" /></a>2V1D&nbsp;B:308-375`. I've edited the attributes

Comment: @Huangism, I'm not sure what you mean. Yes, the container is not wide enough and so it is wrapping. The problem is where it wraps - i.e. at an `&nbsp;` or where there is no space at all as in the code I just posted.

Comment: edit the question and post related html/css code, post a fiddle would be best jsfiddle.net

Comment: float the image and place it inside the paragraph

Comment: I don't see your use of `&nbsp;` anywhere in the posted code? Just spaces?

Comment: @SetSailMedia, no the version I posted was one with "putting them directly next to one another". If you want to add an `&nbsp;` just add one before each digit 2.

Comment: @MikeHometchko,Your answer doesn't put the image inside the paragraph as your comment suggests? But in any case, I need all the images and text inside a single paragraph (there's a whole list of image-text pairs, not just two), so I'm not clear how to apply your suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using a span element and putting the image as a background-image property? This way the page flow isnt obstructed so you can place it anywhere inside the paragraph

Comment: @MikeHometchko, thanks! I've found a solution. I googled span to see what you might be suggesting and came up with `white-space: nowrap` which seems to do what I need. Quite why `&nbsp;` doesn't do what it says on the tin is beyond me, but hey ho.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head><style>.container { width: 400px; }</style></head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<img src="http://lipsum.com/images/lipsum07.gif" style="float: right;" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur velit velit, cursus vitae consequat a, facilisis eu elit. In quis elit non enim semper dictum eget sagittis velit. Mauris nec lectus vitae mi faucibus rutrum non et nunc. Vestibulum ultrices suscipit blandit. Praesent faucibus sagittis arcu, nec convallis dui sodales sit amet. Aenean sapien metus, vestibulum a lacinia id, rhoncus vitae tellus. Fusce enim tortor, suscipit eu tincidunt eu, accumsan eu nulla. Nulla porttitor ullamcorper suscipit. Maecenas vel consectetur ipsum. Mauris blandit sapien et nulla ultrices a consequat nisi sagittis.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, a solution that seems to work is to put a `<span>` around the image and text that need to be kept together and then to set CSS on the span saying: `white-space:nowrap;`